# Cannot select hard drive during installation from bootable usb copy of UBUNTU

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I have latest Ubuntu as of 5/6/2020. I have created bootable copy on usb stick to first try on Hewlett-Packard PACKARD desk computer.

Runs well!

Computer has qty 2 hard drives internal.
Primary drive has Windows 7.
I want to install UBUBTU on 2nd hard drive (500gb).
I have 6gb ram and 6 processors, 64 bit .

How do I select 2nd drive?

altonddavisjr@yahoo.com is direct email.

When I selected to “”INSTALL””, the screens never gave me option to select correct hard drive.

Comment: Please be specific how you define the latest Ubuntu?   (not everyone uses the same criteria on support sites).  Also are you talking server, desktop, alternate ISO etc.

Comment: UNUBTU 20.04 LTS (FOCAL FOSSA)